# How can I loop down row by row until a blank cell is found

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in Excel 2010.  I'm trying to concatenate values in one column, and enter a Char(10) between each cell.  So, I'm working in cells BC2:BC11, and I want to concatenate everything in cell BC1.  I came up with this for BC1:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C & CHAR(10) & R[2]C & CHAR(10) & R[3]C & CHAR(10) & R[4]C & CHAR(10) & R[5]C & CHAR(10) & R[6]C & CHAR(10) & R[7]C & CHAR(10) & R[8]C & CHAR(10) & R[9]C & CHAR(10) & R[10]C"
```

It works, but the problem is that often there will be less than 10 values in my array, so I get a bunch of line breaks piling up at the end, and that messes up something downstream from this.  I'd like to come up with an elegant way of looping through BC2:BC11 and combining everything, with CHAR(10), in between each cell.  Can someone give me a script or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the code you're using now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible code with no loops

```
With ActiveCell
    .value = Join(Application.Transpose(.Offset(1).Resize(10).value), " ") '<--| change "10" to your actual cells number to be considered below active cell
    .value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.value) 
    .Replace " ", Chr(10)
End With
```

Comment: @ryguy7272, did yio get through it?

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways you can achieve this. Assuming that you are always using BC2:BC11 you can create a simple for loop to build the string and then output the result to the active cell.

```
Dim newString As String
For i = 2 To 11

    If ActiveSheet.Range("BC" & i).Text <> "" Then
        If newString = "" Then
            newString = ActiveSheet.Range("BC" & i).Text
        Else
            newString = newString & Chr(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("BC" & i).Text
        End If
    End If

Next

ActiveCell.Value = newString
```

Hope that helps :)